# Access javascript from c++/delphi when meta IE=edge

Tags: javascript, delphi, webbrowser-control, c++builder, meta-tags

I have an application (exe) with a WebBrowser control. I can call Javascript from C++ or Delphi. But I need access to a pseudoStyle on the web page like:

```
document.getElementById("..").pseudoStyle("before","background-color",color);
```

Because IE11 does not support `pseudoStyle` I have to add a meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
```

But then I can not access the Javascript from the application anymore. Then *`GetIDsOfNames`* returns -1, while using IE11 returns the ID correctly.

#### Simple test

Create an executable with a WebBrowser control. Create a HTML file that contains the javascript `"function Test() { alert("here");}"`. Now navigate to the file. It **works**, you can call this "Test" from your exe.

Now insert `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>` into the HTML file. Then you wil not be able to call the Javascript "Test" function anymore.

#### Question

Is it possible to call a Javascript function from an .exe containing a WebBrowser control when the HTML head contains the following, and if so, how?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to state your question in one sentence to make it more clear

Comment: Simple test. you have webBrowser in your exe. Using navigate open some html file with javascript function "Test() { alert("here");}". It WORKS you can call this "Test" from your exe. Insert **<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>** into html file. Then you can not access javascript "Test" function.

Comment: @JozefJašica: do not provide code in comments. That is hardly readable. To me, it is not entirely clear what you are asking, but if you provide a [MCVE] **in your question** (edit it), you may be able to convince people not to close this question and perhaps even to provide an answer. But **what is exactly your question?** Please make it clear, **in your question**, what you actually want to know. Show the Delphi code and if necessary, the corresponding HTML **in your question**.

Comment: FWIW, if you are using C++Builder, then please remove the C++ tag and add the C++Builder tag. Then your answers are more aligned with Delphi and standard C++ users are not bothered with a question that is probably specific to C++Builder. If you are using Viscual C++, than use that tag, for the same reason. This is not a C++ **language** problem.

Comment: Ok, thanx, I added one sentence question.solution for c, c++ or Delphi or C++ builder.

Comment: You still didn't add a [MCVE] or at least the code you use (.pas or .cpp and HTML).